# Always seeing the old PayPal Express Checkout interface in Ionic/Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, paypal, ionic-framework, viewport

I want to implement PayPal Express Checkout the easy way into my Ionic/Cordova app.

I've created a template (paypal.html) which basically just holds the following lines:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="paypal-checkout-form">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="J4N...9PU" />
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.99" id="paypal_amount" />
  <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0.00" />
  <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services" />
  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="DE" />
  <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF" />
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.example.com/some-page-to-return-to" />
</form>
```

In my controller I open this template with the `inAppBrowser` of Ionic, and inject a basic javascript function which submits the `paypal-checkout-form`, like that:

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop', function(e, event){
  $cordovaInAppBrowser.executeScript({
    code: 'var paypalFrm = document.getElementById("paypal-checkout-form"); paypalFrm.submit();'
  });
});
```

I've implemented it that way as I don't have to handle a get_token script from my PHP-Server or any other PayPal requests.

Problem I face now is that not the good-looking new PayPal interface is showing up (just the old gray one), and that the viewport is blown up (the full-fledged PayPal checkout page is shown, not a responsive one).

Is it possible to force to display the new interface? On my computer (same code) everything works as expected.

Thank you.

Comment: did you find any solution for the above problem? We also want to implement the same in our application. Please help.

Best Regards,
Sarim Ghani http://www.i-splendid.com